# get ipa file from iphone store like android

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to get an `ipa` file from iPhone store just like we do for android on google play.

How can I do this? I assume this is possible, as we can easily get `apk` files in the case of android. Can you please show me the steps needed to achieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download applications from iTunes library and then follow given steps:-

1. Go to the Apps section in iTunes, right-click on the app and select "Reveal in Finder"
2. Use the Goto command **(shift+cmd+g)** in Finder to open ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/

Comment: but i have window can i still do it

Comment: Yes, you can do but first you have to install itunes in your system.

Comment: But you can only get iPA file which is made by your organization.Not for other Applications.

Comment: @VikasPandey Yes, he can get ipa file & its content not code.

Comment: can not i do reverse enginnering like for apk's